# jqGrid.info_dialog is not a function, do I have to call extend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I try to use `info_dialog` on my jqGrid, but see `TypeError: $(...).jqGrid.info_dialog is not a function`in the console.

I have (!) not defined my own `info_dialog` function. But I can see one it in `$.extend($.jgrid, ...` like [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/990ea813ef382fb4fd45b38dc769cff4a60a40a8/js/grid.common.js#L184-263), so I was expecting it is available by default.

```
info_dialog : function(caption, content,c_b, modalopt) {
        var mopt = {
            width:290,
            height:'auto',
```

Do I somehow have to enable it for the grid? Or what else do I have to do so I can use the version defined [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/990ea813ef382fb4fd45b38dc769cff4a60a40a8/js/grid.common.js#L184-263) (call `extend` on my grid? ..)

<s>Using 4.6.0 from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqgrid</s>
Now using https://cdnjs.com/libraries/free-jqgrid 4.14.1

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Moreover it's important to see **how you call `info_dialog` in your code**. Depend on the version of jqGrid, which you use, you could initialize `this` correctly like `$.jgrid.info_dialog.call($("#grid")[0],...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid defines not only "standard" methods, which can be used as `$("#grid").jqGrid("methodName", ...)` or `$("#grid").methodName(...)`, but some other methods. The "standard" methods will be registered under `$.fn.jqGrid.methodName` (like `$.fn.jqGrid.editGridRow` function for example) and, if no `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;` is specified before `$.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;`, then under `$.fn.methodName` too.

In other words there are exist only global object `$.fn.jqGrid` or `$.fn`, which contains the "standard" jqGrid methods.

Some other list of methods will be registered under `$.jgrid` instead of `$.fn.jqGrid` or `$.fn`. `info_dialog` is an example of such method. Thus one should use `$.jgrid.info_dialog`, `$.jgrid.jqID`, `$.jgrid.htmlEncode`, `$.jgrid.randId` and so on to use such methods. The most of the methods don't require to initialize `this` (like `$.jgrid.randId()` `$.jgrid.jqID("some.text")`), but some methods require that `this` is initialized to DOM of the grid (the empty `<table>` used to generate the grid).

For example, you can use

```
$grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager", {
    caption: "Test",
    onClickButton: function () {
        $.jgrid.info_dialog.call(this,
            "Warning with two buttons",
            "Click the `test` button",
            "Close",
            {
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "\"text\" button",
                        id: "buttid",
                        onClick: function() {
                            alert("click...");
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        );
    }
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/xLrbdspo/. I use in the demo [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop, but the same works with the retro version 4.6 of jqGrid, which you use.

The final remark. If you know the syntax of TypeScript, that you can find in [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts) answers on many of questions like the usage of `info_dialog`. The methods and properties of `$.jgrid` are described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L546-L642) (inclusive [info_dialog](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L622)). You will find [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.1/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L1666-L1676) additionally some methods `$.fmatter`, `$.jqm`, `$.jqDnR` and `$.unformat` which are the part of jqGrid in the same way like `$.jgrid`.