# JQgrid show custom message on form field

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Using free jqgrid latest version.

In one of the form fields I have onchange event tied up to the textbox.
On the event I make an ajax call to my mvc controller which validates the input that was entered. The only issue I am having is how to show any custom message in case the input was invalid. I have the below code :

```
 {
   name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "text", editable: true, align: "right", editrules: { required: true },
   editoptions:
    {
     dataEvents: [
         {
          type: 'change',
          fn: function (e) {                              
              var input= $(this).val();
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '@Url.Action("Verify", "Home")',
                     data: "id=" + input,
                     type: "GET",
                     success: function (data){
                       if(data == '')
                       {
                         //Show custom message
                       }
                     },
                     error: function (passParams) {
                     }
                    });
                   }
                  }
                 ]}
                }
```

I know I can display the message on the after submit event as below but I want to have custom message on the onchange of the textbox in the form field.

```
afterSubmit: function (response, postData) {
     return [false, 'Custom Message'];
     }
```

Comment: @Oleg  any inputs?

Comment: I'm in business trip and I can't answer on all questions. You don't included in the text of your question which CSS you use: jQuery UI or Bootstrap. In general you make Ajax request absolutely independent from jqGrid. Thus you can display a message inside of `success` or `error` callback using the dialog from the CSS framework, which you use. Alternatively you can use `$.jgrid.info_dialog` method of jqGrid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45786146/315935) for the demo. It's important to use `$.jgrid.info_dialog.call(domOfGrid, ...)`, where `domOfGrid` is like `$("#gridId")`.

Comment: @Oleg I am using "bootstrap css". I am already aware that I can display msges in success or error. May be I dint ask my question properly but I wanted to know how can I display that success or error message. I believe with info_dialog you have shared the solution which is a popup. I am looking for error message to be displayed at the top of the form. The place where we get the required field error messages displayed.

Comment: @Oleg see I created a sample UI where I am looking to show message: https://imgur.com/qXhJkM7  Let me know if this is possible